# CSS Refuses to align middle

Tags: css

I got my link to look and function as i want but for some reason the arrow refuses to align middle with the text on hover

https://jsfiddle.net/Lo24dopt/

```
<div id="hero-content">            
<a href="#roller" class="button ease-in-out" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Learn more </span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that vertical-align works on display: table-cell only.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lo24dopt/1/

```
#hero-content{
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#hero-content a {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Give vertical align to the parent div instead of anchor tag.
[image]